# Change database connection according to domain

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, model

We have multiple domain running on the same application.

Currently , our database environment setting is having config database replicated to every database server. The slave server owns config database and a user database.

We are determining the database connection on RouteServiceProvider.php by checking the used domain.

domain 1 would connect with DB server A ( config_db + A_user_db ) .
Example:

`database.php`

```
'connections' => [  
    'db_config' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => '192.168.0.10', 
        'port' => 'XXXX',
        'database' => 'config_db',
        'username' => 'xxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxx'
    ],    

    'db_user_a' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => '192.168.0.10', 
        'port' => 'XXXX',
        'database' => 'a_user_db',
        'username' => 'xxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxx'
    ],    

]
```

domain 2 would connect with DB server B ( config_db + B_user_db ).
Example:

`database.php`

```
 'connections' => [   
    'db_config' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => '192.168.0.5', 
        'port' => 'XXXX',
        'database' => 'config_db',
        'username' => 'xxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxx'
    ],      
    'db_user_b' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => '192.168.0.5', 
        'port' => 'XXXX',
        'database' => 'b_user_db',
        'username' => 'xxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxx'
    ],      
]
```

The usage of config db which is joined with user database on the same server is as follows:

```
   $db_config = config('database.connections.db_config.database').'.';
   $data['bank_name'] = User::rightJoin($db_config.'config_bank as cb','user.bank_id','=','cb.bank_id')->first(['cb.bank_name']);
```

how do we keep our db_config flexible to be joined with the current user database?

We defined every DB connection of db in database and We tried to use config constant but our model is not able to read the connection of config.

```
   class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
/**
 * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
 *
 * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //
    // get the encrypter service
    $encrypter = app(\Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter::class);

    if(Request()->go) {
         $basepath = Request()->go;
         Cookie::queue('go', $basepath, 60*24*7);                   
    }  

    $row=Partner_domain::where('basepath',$basepath)->first();
    if(($row)){ 
          // returns db_user_a OR db_user_b 
        config(['database.default'     => $row->db_name]); 
    }

    parent::boot();
}
```

}

Expected Result:

`config('database.connections.db_config.database')` would have flexible value .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default connection has been made in the `Partner_domain` model.

Therefore, you must change the settings and then reconnect the default connection.

#### RouteServiceProvider

```
    $row=Partner_domain::where('basepath',$basepath)->first();
    if(($row)){
          // returns db_user_a OR db_user_b
        config(['database.default'     => $row->db_name]);
        config(['database.connections.db_config.host' => '192.168.0.5']);  // change host
        DB::reconnect();
    }
```

> Recommend: Separate the database connection from the `Partner_domain`.  (ex.  database.connections.db_partner_domain)

#### Models

Two database connections can not be joined. You must run the query twice using model relationships as follows:

1. Create `ConfigBank` model.

```
class ConfigBank extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'db_config';

    protected $table = 'config_bank';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'bank_id', 'bank_id');
    }
}
```

2. Add relationship to 'User' model.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function configBank()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ConfigBank::class, 'bank_id', 'bank_id');
    }
}
```

3. Use two database connections.

```
$user = User::find(1);   // test data
if ($user && $user->configBank) {
    $data['bank_name'] = $user->configBank->bank_name;
}
```